# How to get links to namespaced enums to work with Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am having trouble getting a link to an enum to work with Doxygen.

With the files below the link of the return value to the `Status` enum for `someFunction`  works inside the namespace documentation file, but not in the documentation of the `test.hpp` file.

status.hpp

```cpp
/// @file

/// my namespace
namespace bla {

/// some enum
enum class Status { Done, Todo };

} // namespace bla
```

test.hpp

```cpp
/// @file

#include "status.hpp"

namespace bla {

Status someFunction();

} // namespace bla
```

file reference

[image: test.hpp file]

namespace reference

[image]

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What are the settings you use different from the default settings (i.e.the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`).

Comment: @albert I am using 1.9.6 and I only set the INPUT to those two files.

Comment: Looks lkike the namespace is not taken into account for the type as `bla::Status someQualifiedFunction();` is linked when adding it to `test.hpp` (and also not when moving it into `status.hpp`, Note that on the namespace page the link is present. Best is to file an issue in the doxygen issue tracker with attached a, small, self contained example (source+configuration file in a, compressed, tar or zip file) that allows to reproduce the problem? Please don't add external links as they might not be persistent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I created an issue. https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9850